# Moving randomly svg objects using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, move

I want to move my svg objects randomly using vanilla javascript,
i make it to move element by adding value to cx by 10px but it likes it is jumping, is there any other way to move it smoothly, keyframes does not work. and javascript is used inside svg file, i need to achive effect like bouncing balls just with these elements
Effect like this one: 
https://codepen.io/pintergabor/pen/DywHc

This should be used as background picture.

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<defs>
    <style>
        .cls-1 {
            fill: url(#linear-gradient);
        }

        .cls-2 {
            fill: url(#linear-gradient-2);
        }

        .cls-3 {
            fill: url(#linear-gradient-3);
        }
        #circle{
            animate: circle 4s infinite linear;
        }
        @keyframes circle{
            to{
                transform: translate(55rem, 15px);
            }
        }
    </style>


    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="61.83" y1="217.56" x2="61.83" y2="256.64" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9dcb3b" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#aa2d23" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="316.43" y1="64.69" x2="316.43" y2="98.31" xlink:href="#linear-gradient" />
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="321.31" y1="319.11" x2="321.31" y2="396.98" xlink:href="#linear-gradient" />
</defs>
<title>elements</title>
<circle id="circle" class="cls-1" cx="61.83" cy="237.1" r="19.54" />
<polygon id="triangle" class="cls-2" points="316.43 64.69 297.01 98.31 335.84 98.31 316.43 64.69" />
<path id="plus" class="cls-3" d="M323.9,397h-5.18V319.11h5.18Zm36.35-36.35v-5.17H282.37v5.17Z" />
```

Comment: You could use an interpolation library, such as [ola](https://github.com/franciscop/ola).

Comment: You should be using CSS for animations of this nature

Comment: did our answers below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a loop to do that using "vanilla" javascript.

A basic way to do that would be :

```
let fps = 60  // frames per second

function loop(){
   console.log('in loop')
}

window.setInterval(loop, 1000 / fps)
```

Then in the loop function move your svg elements as you'd like.

Some libraries help a lot with this. A few coming to mind are SVG.js, two.js, velocity.js...

Answer (score 0):

You can animate elements or classes like this:

```
circle, my-class {
  animation: move 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```